# What's the deal with propane fittings?

Tags: propane

I'm going to be removing the regulator off a grill to use with my RV since the port the gas will be coming from is already low pressure.  As I search for fittings, will any brass-like fitting be sufficient?

For example, [https://www.amazon.com/gp/product/B003OYJF32/ref=ox_sc_sfl_title_2?ie=UTF8&psc=1&smid=ATVPDKIKX0DER](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B003OYJF32) ..

It's lead free brass with NPT threads (which I'm guessing is better?) Anything I should stay away from? Anything I should seek out?  I think what gave me pause about this particular fitting is it has a rougher brass appearance and doesn't specifically say anything about what kind of pipe it should be used on (some of the other fittings say gas, etc)

As long as the fittings are brass and don't leak, do I have anything to be overly concerned about?

Comment: You should be most concerned that the ratings of the "re-purposed" grill regulator matches that of your original RV regulator (the pressure is normally stated as "in./Hg" or "in./H20" or "inches water column") in the U.S. If the pressure/flow rating is not correct you could have appliance malfunction causing problems up to and including death by fire or CO poisoning.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Short answer, no.

From my personal experience with replacing the gas line for my water heater:

1. Don't buy on Amazon. Go to your local store if possible because if you buy the wrong thing (which you'll inevitably do if you don't know exactly what you're doing), returning it is a pain. Besides that, some plumbing products on Amazon seem to be more expensive for some reason.
2. All pipe should have NPT threads. Lead free brass is only useful when you're dealing with potable water. Gas applications shouldn't matter
3. I just used black steel because it's significantly cheaper than brass and since there's no water running through it to rust it, it'll work just fine.
4. Make sure you use a teflon type tape that is rated for gas lines.

Comment: Amazon and its marketplace partners who "ship from Amazon warehouses" must build in the costs of unit packaging, barcoding, warehousing and shipping.  Shipping because so many Amazon customers are Amazon Prime.  This makes it prohibitive for Amazon to sell $1 items.  If you really must mail order those things, try McMaster-Carr, but I'd recommend your local family owned lumberyard or plumbing supply.